# How to apply CNN on a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

now I am trying to build a deep learning model as a classifier. My input is a 2D dataframe. I was wondering if it is possible to use CNN layer in the model.
My data looks like this way:

```
x_train <- data.frame(pain = c(rep(c(0,1), c(4,5))),
                      gender = c(rep(c(0,1), c(3,6))),
                      age = c(runif(9,0,1)))
y_train <- data.frame(illness = c(rep(c(0,1), c(2,2)), rep(c(0,1), c(3,2))))
```

Now I construct a model like this way:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  layer_conv_1d(filters = 1, kernel_size = 2, activation = "elu", 
                input_shape = c(3,1)) %>%
  # layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2,2)) %>% 
  layer_conv_1d(filters = 1, kernel_size = 2, activation = "elu") %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size = 2) %>% 
    layer_dropout(0.5) %>%
  layer_dense(
    units = 5,
    activation = "elu"
  ) %>%
  layer_dropout(0.3) %>%
  layer_dense(
  units = 3,
  activation = "elu"
  ) %>%
  layer_dropout(0.1) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "elu")

model %>% compile(
  loss = "mean_squared_error",
  optimizer = "SGD",
  metrics = c('mae', 'acc') # "accuracy"
  )
```

But it doesn't work and tells me it needs a 3 dimensions input

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
>   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_33_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (9, 3)

Could anyone give me some advice about that? Thanks a lot for your help : )